# Is there a standalone version of the new react-dom package?

Tags: reactjs, amd

The title says it all. Since 0.14 (yesterday) ReactJS has been split into react and react-dom packages (for good reason).

For goofy reasons, I'm loading react with AMD. This has worked up until now using their standalone version on the downloads page, but even though they've updated this page to point to v0.14.0, they don't have a standalone version of react-dom.

Is this on it's way? Is there some other way to include react/react-dom with AMD?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Looks like it's up [here on cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react/). Should have looked their first.